# Need to create PDF using edit blob data in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, pdf

I am developing `Rails application` where need to `create PDF`  using store pdf as a `BLOB data in MySQL` field.

Now i can download it using `BLOB` data but first i have to edit it means replace some content like `{NAME}` to original user name.

Now i tried to `replace name in BLOB data` which fetch from DB then create PDF using send_data but did not any changed and create issue in PDF generate.

```
bContent = @document.document_content.bContent.gsub(/{NAME}/, "ADOBE")

send_data(bContent,
            type: "application/pdf",
            filename: file_name)
```

Comment: Does @new_content variable exist in your code?

Comment: ohh sorry its update question now. Please check it.